# Way to work out itertools in forloop to stop MemoryError

Tags: python, python-itertools

The following code failes due to `MemoryError`. I believe this is because it is calculating the itertools part in one go. Is it possible for itertools to be calculate itself along with my for loops in to avoid filling up my RAM.

(or is the only option to get a bigger computer!)

Please advise -

---

```
N = 8
a = TWFclass(N)
b = []
c = np.zeros_like(a.TWFm)
for i in np.array(list(itertools.product(range(N), repeat=int(N*np.log2(N))))):
    a.change(i.reshape(N, int(np.log2(N))))
    if a.check(16):
        b.append(a.TWFm)
```

A bit of info about code:

-the itertools statement generates a the numbers for the matrix a.TWFm

-this is then assigned to the a.TWFm via the .change function

-.check function returns true or false from some calculation appending it to list b for analysis later on

---

**EDIT (answers to comments)**

comment 1)

*`np.array` requires a list ? It won't take whatever `itertools.product` returns ?*

itertools has to have a list to unpack/whatever (i.e. drag values out the object) as not having list causes the error `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`

comment 2)

*I'm pretty sure you can't have a "lazy" array; whether you give it a list or (even if supported) a generator as an argument, the resulting array will have all the data in memory (albeit stored as compactly as possible).*

I can see your point, if i alter my question slightly to say that i know that I have a for loop which lasts x = N**(log2(N)*N) do you know if itertools lets you work out the single `itertools.product` of loop number x? Hope that makes sense...

comment 3)

*Just curious... what are `TWFclass` and `TFWm`? Are your classes? Part of a library I do not know?*

No it is my own class where `TWFm` is a matrix of (N, log2(N)) and `TWFclass` is the class name...

i.e. i have

```
class TWFclass(N):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.TWFm = np.zeros([self.N, int(np.log2(self.N))])
```

Comment: `np.array` requires a `list` ? It won't take whatever `itertools.product` returns ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't have a "lazy" array; whether you give it a list or (even if supported) a generator as an argument, the resulting array will have all the data in memory (albeit stored as compactly as possible).

Comment: Just curious... what are `TWFclass` and `TFWm`? Are your classes? Part of a library I do not know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why convert an iterator to an array or a list if you consume it element-by-element anyway?

The following should work just as well:

```
for i in itertools.product(range(N), repeat=int(N*np.log2(N))):
    ...
```